# Create functions for statistic median

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function to find  medians using the loop "for". At this moment, this is my function:

```
mediana <- function (x,k=3){
  n<-length(x)
  r_med <- NULL
  m <- matrix(x,n,k)
  for (i in k){
    r_med[i]<-apply(m,1,median)[1:(n-k+1)]
  }
}
```

But when I try to probe the function, this warning message appears:

```
Warning message:
In r_med[i] <- apply(m, 1, median)[1:(n - k + 1)] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Can anyone help me with my problem? I'm beginner in R and I'm suffering a  lot to understand the programming!

Thanks!

Comment: Use function `rollapply` from package zoo. And never, ever grow an object in a loop like you are trying to do with `r_med`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to find a function, use `rollapply` as Roland suggests.  If you are trying to teach yourself some programming continue reading.

If I understand correctly, by 'running median' you mean take the median of every `k` elements.  For example:

```
> runif(9)
[1] 0.5889687801 0.9012693244 0.9394947358 0.3996177884 0.9639447967 0.7152831559 0.1913678751 0.7477577361 0.5264336797
```

If `k=3` the first median would of `0.589, 0.901, & 0.939`, the second `0.901, 0.939, & 0.399`, etc.

If so, you don't need the `apply` or `matrix` statements as you can index a vector.

The revised function would look like this:

```
mediana <- function (x,k=3){
  n<-length(x)
  r_med <- vector("numeric", n-k+1)
  for (i in seq(n-k+1)){
    r_med[i] <- median(x[i:(i+k-1)])
  }
  return(r_med)
}
```

A few programming points:

1. Your loop needs something to iterate over, either something like `1:k` or using `seq`.  The number of combinations will be `n-k+1` so you use that.
2. As noted in the comments by Roland, you shouldn't grow objects in loops.  Specify the size of the object you are filling (e.g. `vector("numeric", n-k+1)`)
3. Although somewhat stylistic, it is good form to provide a `return` statement.  In a simple function like this it isn't as much of an issue but good for clarity.